# How to click on button using several conditions

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I try to press a button using selenium. How do I click on a particular button using several conditions? (https://ibb.co/cJZxD7b) describing image

I have already tried something like this `//span[text()=1.01]`, but what if webpage have few buttons with the same text.

```
wait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='45.00 7.75 1.04'] and //span[text()=1.04"))).click()
```

I expect to click on particular button

Comment: You are trying to locate two elements in one xpath?

Comment: Please share html code here.

Comment: @MosheSlavin, I am trying to find exact element. Like, imagine that there are many divs in which there are many more spans. So here I am trying to find a specific one span using the text from div. I hope You understand

Comment: @KajalKundu here are images 1) https://imgur.com/a/cffQtER 2) https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501623094073

Comment: I have checked that snapshot.Its not clear at all.Could you please expand this Div section and post it here.

Comment: @KajalKundu https://imgur.com/k6ysCzJ Hope this will help

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with xpath

```
//span[@class='stn-val']
```

But it would probably be the best if you shared more of the HTML code because now I'm only guessing based on what I see.

Also, are you getting any error messages?

**UPDATE:**

Based on HTML posted in comments, use this selector:

```
//div[@class="st-col-bet-container"][2]/ul/li[3]/span
```

For tips on xpath selectors, see [here](https://devhints.io/xpath).

Comment: Watch this example https://ibb.co/3d7hYd9 . How do I click on second div where span text is 13.00

Comment: Try `//div[@class="st-col-bet-container"][2]/ul/li[3]/span`.